# ¿Por qué no funciona el borrado de la terminal en Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio, terminal

He programado una cuenta atrás en Python en Visual Studio (no VSC) para mi hora de salida del trabajo dependiendo del día, la hora de entrada, los fichajes y tal, y hasta ahora era estático (una sola muestra por pantalla y fin). Pero ahora he intentado que se vaya actualizando periódicamente, pero el comando de borrado de terminal solo me escribe el símbolo "♀" y sigue escribiendo debajo.

CÓDIGO:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
from os import system

while True:
    ...
    system('cls')
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

SALIDA:
[image: salida de terminal]

Comment: Si esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73154247) en el sitio en inglés responde a tu pregunta, ponla como respuesta (no el enlace, sino la explicación como tal) :)

Comment: @padaleiana GRACIAS!

Comment: ¿Respondió ese enlace a tu pregunta?

Comment: Sí, muchas gracias. Y yo volviéndome loco por una simple casilla.

Comment: ¡Entonces redactalo como respuesta, y [aceptala](/help/accepted-answer)! Recordá que otros puede que tengan el mismo problema que vos, y el enlace que te dejé como comentario, puede que alguna vez se rompa. Por eso te decía que pongas la explicación como tal :) No olvides hacer el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1):

1. En el menú superior ir a *Herramientas > Opciones* y se abrirá una nueva ventana.
2. En *Entorno > Python > Depuración* desmarcar la opción "[x] Resultado del programa tee en la Ventana de salida de depuración"